# Is 'apply' in webpack plugin same as 'apply' in js which means change this

Tags: javascript, webpack

As title said, if you write a webpack plugin, you should defined apply method in it. like below code:

```
class TestPlugin () {
    apply(compiler) {
        // do something with compiler
    }
}
```

And when you run webpack it will invoke apply method in each plugin and pass compiler.
But there is confusion about 'apply' in js functiion. like:

```
function foo() {
}
foo.apply(object)
```

Above means change the 'this' reference. So is 'apply' in webpack plugin same as 'apply' in js which means change this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding the ‘apply’ in webpack it is “just” a method that must be named ‘apply’ by convention and has nothing to do with the ‘apply’ prototype in ‘Function.prototype.apply()’.